# Method overriding alternative in Rust

Tags: inheritance, rust, overriding

I'm a little confused about the absence of struct inheritance and method overriding in Rust.

When we want to implement, for example, GUI library with ability to customize controls look, in other popular object-oriented languages like Java, C# etc. we just make some rendering methods virtual to let user extend our control element classes and override these methods to change rendering logic.

Since Rust doesn't have any struct inheritance and method overriding, could you please explain me how to implement similar functionality in the Rust manner?

Comment: Have you seen traits yet?

Comment: @mcarton Of cource I've seen them. But I still don't understand how to implement this with them. If you know, can you please answer my question?

Comment: When you have a hammer, everything looks like a nail. When you have inheritance, everything looks like a class hierarchy. Rust doesn't have inheritance, but it does have traits. It's hard to answer a question that's so broad; the answer is something along the lines of "it depends on which feature of inheritance is particularly useful in any given scenario" which while 100% accurate is not so very helpful.

Comment: @trentcl I've thought that example I've gave is enough to understand which feature of inheritance I'm interested in. I want to give user of my library an ability to customize some parts of its code. You can explain me how to do this on the same example. If you write a GUI library in rust and want to give user controls look customization, how exactly would you do that?

Comment: Customize the look of a control? Like setting the size or color of a button? That doesn't seem to require inheritance; you can always just write `button.size = (300, 500)` or `button.color = "red"`. And of course you can wrap this in a custom function if you need it a lot, just like you would with any other code... Perhaps there's something more profound I'm missing that I would understand implicitly if I wrote a lot of GUIs, but that's not really my area.

Comment: @trentcl LOL. Not such primitive customization. How about to give user more freedom? Not just configure some attributes but change rendering logic completely. E.g. make button look like NOT button. Make it rounded. Or animated. Or rounded and animated. Or anything he wants. But only rendering without touching other logic.

Comment: Fine, `button.renderer = my_renderer` then. There's even a couple different ways that could work; `Button` could be parameterized over its renderer type, or you could use type erasure, or `Renderer` could be a library type that you customize by passing callbacks to its constructor.

Comment: Rather than saying `class RoundedButton extends Button` you say `struct Button<T: ButtonRenderer> { renderer: T }` for example. Or maybe you use a trait object or an enum. You could make `Button` implement a `Widget` trait, so that you can then say `impl<T: ButtonRenderer> Widget for Button<T>` or something like that.

Comment: Searching for `gui` on [`crates.io`](https://crates.io/search?q=gui) returns 380 results. You can look at them to see how they do it.

Comment: URLO is probably a better place to discuss this; here are some recent (and a few not-so-recent) threads: [1](https://users.rust-lang.org/t/rust-koans/2408/2) [2](https://users.rust-lang.org/t/how-to-model-inheritance-hierarchy/33380) [3](https://users.rust-lang.org/t/how-to-implement-inheritance-like-feature-for-rust/31159) [4](https://users.rust-lang.org/t/is-rust-oop-if-not-what-is-it-oriented-to/30777) [5](https://users.rust-lang.org/t/multilevel-inheritance/27785) [6](https://users.rust-lang.org/t/why-not-just-add-classes/4618) [7](https://users.rust-lang.org/t/inheritance-and-rust/3998)

Comment: @OptimisticPeach I like your proposal with `struct Button<T: ButtonRenderer>` but I don't understand how to make the `Button` struct to have a default renderer which is used simply by creating button object like this: `let b = Button::new()` without any generics. Is it possible? If yes, could you pls provide an example?

Comment: Sure, you can make your generic parameter have a default value (You can't make a value parameter do this though); you could write `struct Button<T: ButtonRenderer = DefaultRenderer> { renderer: T }` and then make your `new` impl only exist when you can actually create a new `T`. This is done in the standard library for the `HashMap` and `HashSet` hashers, so that you don't have to worry about the hasher as a regular user, but if you want to change it you're allowed to.

Comment: @OptimisticPeach Thank you! This is exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

In programming there are different [paradigms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_programming_paradigms), object orientation is only one of them. Other examples are: imperative programming, functional programming, and so on.

There is no difference in what can be done with all these paradigms, with all of them you can implement algorithms for exactly the same set of problems. This can be easily proven by the fact that you can write compilers that convert a program in on of the languages/paradigms to a target in a different language. At the end all programs get executed on the same CPU, that does not know anything about object orientation at all.

Even not all OOP languages support inheritance while others even support inheritance from multiple classes. In modern theory about OOP it's even more and more questioned if inheritance is a good thing or not. There is the doctrine of [composition over inheritance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance) that recommends to replace sub-classing with composition.

In your example that means that instead of having a class that completely handles everything related to the button, you split this logic into different parts. In one of your comments you had the example of a button you want to look differently. This can be done, by moving the complete display code to a delegate of the button class. In case you want to give the button a complete different appearance you just set a different display delegate to the button, that implements the different layout (maybe again by composing different ready made parts).

In the case of Rust, this composition can easily be made with traits. In OOP speak they are interfaces. So you can define a trait that some code that implements the rendering has to implement and assign this to the button class, struct, whatever you name it. Every time the button needs to be rendered, it will delegate the job to the rendering delegate that is currently configured in it.

But still this is very much just OOP thinking. Rust is multi paradigm. So you might decide not to do OOP at all. For example in functional programming you might do this with high order functions, or separating the rendering from other aspects (like click processing, or holding the state of the application) completely. An example for the later you can see in [React](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/React_(web_framework)) (JavaScript), om.next or [Re-frame](https://github.com/day8/re-frame) (ClojureScript), or the [Elm Architecture](https://guide.elm-lang.org/architecture/) (Elm).